# ASP.NET Core asp-for input tag helper setting zero value

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC web application. I'm passing a model to a partial view that I'm showing in a modal window (via ajax call). There is a lot of code (`.cshtml`, controller, model) so let me first try this with a minimum amount of code shared.

In my model there are several properties, but the relevant to the problem are the following four:

```cs
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Select client!")]
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Select client!")]
public int IdClient { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Select group!")]
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Select group!")]
public int IdGroup { get; set; }

public string Mode { get; set; }
public string TempFile { get; set; }
```

When editing a record I want to write this properties into hidden input fields like this:

```html
<form asp-controller="Racuni" asp-action="Save" >

    <input asp-for="IdClient" type="hidden" />
    <input asp-for="IdGroup" type="hidden" />
    <input asp-for="Mode" type="hidden" />
    <input asp-for="TempFile" type="hidden" />

    @* ... *@
</form>
```

At the time of passing the values to cshtml from the controller:

```cs
// view
return PartialView("_PartialDetail", model);
```

all four properties have values (> 0 for integers and !="" for strings).

Also, if I debug the `.cshtml` before the hidden inputs, all four properties have values, but in the resulting html in the browser, the first two inputs (`IdClient` and `IdGroup`) have values = 0. On the other hand, both strings (`Mode` and `Tempfile`) are OK.

What could be the problem? Are we not suppose to use asp-for helper in hidden fields?

Note: I already found a workaround. If I change the `.cshtml` code for the two integer values to explicitly set the values like this:

```html
<input asp-for="IdClient" value="@Model.IdClient" type="hidden" />
<input asp-for="IdGroup" value="@Model.IdGroup" type="hidden" />
```

then the values get set correctly.